# 'Capacitor/Capacitor.h' file not found trying to create Capacitor Plugin

Tags: swift, objective-c, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Hey I'm trying to complete this tutorial here https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/custom-code whenever I try and create EchoPlugin.m I get this error 'Capacitor/Capacitor.h' file not found. I've added capacitor to my app and I've found the capacitor stuff in my npm package 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios' and I can see the Capacitor stuff in my Development Pods. Pretty new to Swift and mobile dev any help is greatly appreciated

import 'Capacitor/Capacitor.h in a objective-c file for the echo plugin

Comment: solved: xcode did not have full disk access on my mac